# How do I call a javascript function once multiple events occur?

Tags: javascript, events, model-view-controller

I know how to call a javascript function once one event occurs. However, I do not know how to call a javascript function once multiple events occur.

Background: I am letting users use 3 drag down lists to select a day, month, and year. I want it so that after a user selects a day, month, and year, a javascript function gets called if the date is not valid.

Comment: Is there a default option in the select when no value is selected?

Comment: You can call a method on each dropdown change and have logic to read the selected data in that method.

Comment: Is there a default option in the select when no value is selected? Yes